# Create matrix using hashtable MATLAB

Tags: matlab, containers

I am using hashtable (`containers.map` ) in MATLAB, and now I want to create a matrix with that information. So when I run my hashtable and then insert my text files for each type I get on my command window something like that:

**edit**

```
F = listdlg('PromptString','Different types', 'SelectionMode',...
    'single', 'ListString',E, 'Name','Select a type','ListSize',[230 130]);

        [files,path] = uigetfile ('*.txt','Select your text files',...
            'MultiSelect','on');
```

where `E` is just the user's input which in this case is `pink`, `purple` and `yellow`.

```
%save for each type the user enters the corresponding text files he
            %wants to train
            %A Map object is a data structure that allows you to retrieve values 
            %using a corresponding key. Keys can be real numbers or text strings
            %and provide more flexibility for data access than array indices, 
            %which must be positive integers. Values can be scalar or nonscalar arrays.



handles.map (E(F,:)) = files;
handles.map
a = handles.map.values
b = handles.map.keys
handles.map.size
b = 

    {1x3 cell}    {1x6 cell}    {1x4 cell}


a = 

    'pink  '    'purple'    'yellow'
```

So I want now to the the total number of `b` to be the number of rows on my matrix `m` ; so a total number of rows 14 and each bit from `a` to be a column; so a total of 3 columns. But I want to create a binary matrix where each column will identify different type. Finally I will have created a matrix like that:

```
  m =[1 0 0
     1 0 0
     1 0 0
     0 1 0
     0 1 0
     0 1 0
     0 1 0
     0 1 0
     0 1 0
     0 0 1
     0 0 1
     0 0 1
     0 0 1];
```

Where the first 3 rows of the matrix says that there are 3text files of type `pink`, the next 6 rows : 6 text files of type `purple` and the last 4: 4 text files of type `yellow`.

I hope that now is more clear. :)

Any help would be appreciated! :) x

Comment: Still not entirely clear; could you explain in more detail what the keys and values in your Map are?  It would be best if you could create a minimal working example where you populate the Map with values, and then explain what output you would like.

Comment: thanks.. I have just edited it, I hope I was more clear now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So something like this?

```
val = cellfun(@length, b)';

m = 0;
for v = 1:size(val)
  m(end:end+val(v)-1,v) = 1;
end
```

Comment: @Chrysovalando Wait... I thought you were saying `b` is your input and `m` is your desired output? Is that not the case

Comment: yes that is the case.. but when I use it in my code I only get one column of 1 but if I run it as it is I get what I want.. So probably I have something crazy going on my code :/

Comment: please see now my original post :)

Comment: @Chrysovalando Try and transpose my original `val` calc, see my edit